# Fixed parameter tractability

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, fixed-parameter-tractable

Lets say I have an algorithm with complexity $O(n^k)$ where $n$ is the size of the input and $k$ is a parameter.
Clearly this is superpolynomial; but in fixed parameter tractability we restrict $k$ to some value. It becomes fixed parameter tractable if the resulting complexity is $O(f(k)*n^c)$. My gut tells me that this is the case for this example, but I can't connect the dots yet. Can I just subsitute the $c$ in the equation by $k$ and then I'm done?

Answer (score 4):

Such an algorithm shows that the problem is in [XP<sub>unif</sub>](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:X#xpuniform), but does not show membership in [FPT](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:F#fpt).

Answer (score 3):

$n$ and $k$ are both parameters that can increase to arbitrarily large values, 
not constants. 
Your function is $g(n,k) = n^k$ and 
it is not in $O(f(k)*n^c)$ for any function $f$ and constant $c$.

The whole point here is that $f$ does not depend on $n$ but only on $k$ and 
the exponent $c$ in $n^c$ is an absolute constant 
that does not depend on $k$ or $n$.